# What does this FreeType2 error code mean?

Tags: freetype, freetype2

Using FreeType2, I'm calling `FT_Load_Glyph`, and getting a return value of 0xFFFFFFFF. According to https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-base_interface.html#ft_load_glyph, a non-zero value means an error.

However, this error isn't listed at https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-error_code_values.html. Can anyone explain to me what this error code means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question over at https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/freetype/freetype/-/issues/1063#note_955441, and was told that it is `invalid offset (11040)`.